# Proof of the universal property of the quotient topology

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces, universal-property

In this question:
[universal property in quotient topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1493993/universal-property-in-quotient-topology)
I saw the following theorem:

> Let $X$ be a topological space and $\sim$ an equivalence relation on $X$. Let $\pi: X\to X/{\sim}$ be the canonical projection. If $g : X → Z$ is a continuous map such that $a \sim b$ implies $g(a) = g(b)$ for all $a$ and $b$ in $X$, then there exists a unique continuous map $f : X/{\sim} → Z$ such that $g = f ∘ \pi$.

I was wondering how one would prove this.

Comment: Can you define such a map $f$ first? Since $\pi$ is a quotient map, you can use that $f\circ \pi$ is continuous iff $f$ is.

Comment: Notice this conspicuous difference: $$f : X/\sim \to Z$$ $$f : X/{\sim} \to Z$$ Since "$\sim$" is a binary relation symbol, a certain amount of space appears to its left and right in things like $a\sim b$.  That spacing is inappropriate in $f : X/{\sim} \to Z$, and is avoided by coding it as f : X/{\sim} \to Z.  That way there's nothing to its left or right, so that spacing isn't there.  I edited the question accordingly. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Gee, I hadnt noticed that. Thanks!

Comment: It seems clear what the function would be; the problem then is to prove it's continuous. $\qquad$

Comment: @sqtrat I think that $f(\pi(a))=g(a)$

Comment: @newguy Yes, see answer by Brian M. Scott below.

Comment: As always, first try a direct approach based on the def'ns.It often works. In this case, the def'n of the quotient topology. See Brian M. Scott's A.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For $x\in X$ let $[x]$ denote that $\sim$-equivalence class of $x$; $X/{\sim}=\{[x]:x\in X\}$. To show that such an $f$ exists, we simply define it: for $[x]\in X/{\sim}$ let $f([x])=g(x)$. Now use the fact that $g$ is constant on $[x]$ to show that $f$ is well-defined.

To show that $f$ is unique, suppose that $h:X/{\sim}\to Z$ is continuous and satisfies $g=h\circ\pi$. Let $[x]\in X/{\sim}$ be arbitrary. Then

$$f([x])=(f\circ\pi)(x)=g(x)=(h\circ\pi)(x)=h([x])\;,$$

and hence $f=h$.

To show that $f$ is continuous, let $U$ be an open set in $Z$. Show that $$f^{-1}[U]=\{[x]\in X/{\sim}:x\in g^{-1}[U]\}\;,$$ and then use the fact that $X/{\sim}$ bears the quotient topology to conclude that $f^{-1}[U]$ is open in $X/{\sim}$.

Comment: Hi, i think you might still need to show that $f$ must be continuous

Comment: @Khoria Not necessary, since $\pi$ is a quotient map.

Comment: And how would I show continuity?

Comment: @newguy: Sorry: I got called away before I was finished. I’ve added a sketch of that argument to my answer.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Could you please clarify this statement: *Now use the fact that  is constant on [] to show that  is well-defined.*? I have not really understood it.

Comment: @rainman: I defined $f([x])$ to be $g(x)$. However, if $y\in[x]$, then $[y]=[x]$, and according to my definition $f([y])=g(y)$. Since $[x]=[y]$, this means that $f([x])$ has to be $g(y)$, too. And **that** means that my definition makes no sense if $g(x)\ne g(y)$. That is, $f$ is not well-defined if different representatives of a $\sim$-equivalence class can be treated differently by $g$.

Comment: @Brian M. Scott: Thank you so much. I appreciate it.

Comment: @rainman: You’re very welcome.