# Understanding a chart of an atlas of the $\mathbb{R}P^n$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, projective-space

Consider the picture description given here: [Understanding the Atlas of $\mathbb RP^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4384016/understanding-the-atlas-of-mathbb-rpn). Let $\pi$ be the canonical projection $\pi:\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\setminus\{0\}\to \mathbb{R}P^n$. In the comments, and in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_space#Topology), the inverse of the chart $\varphi_i:\pi(U_i)\to \mathbb{R}^n, \varphi_i(x_1,\dots,x_{n+1}) = \left(\frac{x_1}{x_i},\dots,\hat{x}_i,\dots,\frac{x_1}{x_i}\right)$ ,$U_i = \{(x_1,\dots,x_{n+1}) \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}\setminus\{0\}\mid x_i \neq 0\}$ (where the hat denotes a coordinate that is to be left out), is claimed to be $\varphi_i^{-1}(x_1,\dots,x_n) = (x_1,\dots,x_{i-1},1,x_{i},\dots,x_{n})$. What I don't understand is that how is $\varphi^{-1}_i$ the inverse of $\varphi_i$, when the $i$th coordinate is mapped back to $1$, while it could have been, say, $x_i = 0.5$?

As an additional question, under the assumption that the given mappings are in fact charts, wouldn't they also work for $\overline{U}_i = \{(x_1,\dots,x_{n + 1})\in \mathbb{S}^n \subset \mathbb{R}^{n+1}\mid x_i \neq 0\}$?

Comment: There's an equivalence relation or class missing.

Comment: @psl2Z What do you mean?

Comment: $x \sim y$ for $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}\setminus\{0\}$ precisely if there is some $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ with $y = \lambda x$. The $U_i$ should be $\pi(U_i)$, where $\pi$ is the canonical projection $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\setminus\{0\} \to \mathbb{R}P^n$.

Comment: @psl2Z I see! However, even with this modification, I don't really understand why the claimed inverse mapping is in fact an inverse mapping.

Comment: In each equivalence class there is precisely one element with "1" in the $i$-th place.

Comment: Several mistakes. You need $\pi$ mapping $\Bbb R^{n+1}\setminus \{0\}$, and you need $\varphi$ applied to the equivalence class $[x_1,\dots,x_{n+1}]$.

Comment: An example for $n=4$ and $i=2$: $\phi_2(x_1, 0.5, x_3, x_4) = (2 x_1, 2 x_3, 2x_4)$, and $\phi^{-1}(2x_1, 2x_3, 2x_4) = (x_1, 1, x_3, x4)$. But as far as as $\mathbb R P^3$ is concerned, $(x_1, 0.5, x_3, x_4)$ and $(2x_1, 1, 2x_3, 2x_4)$ denote the same point.

Comment: @blamocur How is $\varphi^{-1}(2x_1, 2x_3, 2x_4) = (x_1, 1, x_3, x_4)$? Shouldn't the image be either $(2x_1, 1, 2x_3, 2x_4)$ or $(x_1, 0.5, x_3, x_4)$ like you wrote?

Comment: @SickSeries You are right, it should be $(2x_1,1,2x_3,2x_4)$ -- thanks for catching the typo.