Showing that $ker(A)^\perp$ is the weak-* closure of $im(A*)$
I am trying to show that $ker(A)^\perp$ equals the weak-* closure of $im(A^*)$ (Denoted by $cl(im(A^*))$), where $A: X \to Y$ is a continuous linear map between Banach spaces, where $A^*$ denotes the adjoint operator of $A$.
I have shown that $cl(im(A^*)) \subset ker(A)^\perp$. I am also pretty confident about this inclusion.
However, for the other inclusion I would like some verification of my proof.
Let $x' \in ker(A)^\perp$, then define $\tilde T: im(A) \to \mathbb{K}$, where $\mathbb{K}$ is either $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, by $\tilde T(y) = x'(x)$ if $Ax=y$. It can then be shown that $\tilde T$ is continuous and can thus be extended to a continuous linear functional $T: Y \to \mathbb{K}$.
Then $(A^* T)(x) = T(Ax) = \tilde T (Ax) = x'(x)$ and thus $ (A^* T) = x'$. Thus, $x' \in im(A^*)$, thus in particular in $cl(im(A^*))$.
Which concludes the proof.
I am unsure if this is correct, since I have not used the closure in the second part. Am I missing something. I would appreciate some feedback.

Why is $\tilde T$ continuous?

@AnneBauval It is a bit tedious to show, but basically $|\tilde T(y)| = |x'(x)| \leq ||x'|| ||x||$ and then we bound $||x||$ by playing with the unique map from the universal property in the quotient topology https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1493993/universal-property-in-quotient-topology

This was my first thought, but the problem (for the "quotient topology") is precisely that our $im(A)$ may not be closed.

Usually statements that require showing a subspace is (weak star) dense use a geometric Hahn Banach argument

@AnneBauval you are correct, I have not looked at my solution carefully and the part that $\tilde T$ is continuous was taken from a proof, where $im(A)$ was closed. Thus my proof above is incorrect. Do you have by any chance a reference for a valid proof? Ideally, without a geometric version of Hahn-Banach

Suppose for a contradiction that the weak$^*$ closure $cl(im(A^*))$ is not equal to $\ker(A)^\perp$. Then, there exists $f\in\ker(A)^\perp$, $f\notin cl(im(A^*))$. By Hahn-Banach theorem, there exists a weak$^*$ continuous linear functional $\mu:X^*\to\mathbb{K}$ such that $$\mathbf{\mu(f) = 1}, \hspace{4mm} cl(im(A^*))\subseteq \ker\mu. $$
Since $\mu$ is weak$^*$ continuous, $\exists x_0\in X \hspace{2mm} \mu(f)=f(x_0)\hspace{2mm}\forall f\in X^*$.
$cl(im(A^*))\subseteq ker\mu 
\Rightarrow \mu(A^*g) = 0 \hspace {2mm} \forall g\in Y^*
\Rightarrow g(Ax_0) = 0 \hspace {2mm} \forall g\in Y^*
\Rightarrow Ax_0=0 \Rightarrow \mathbf{f(x_0)=0}$. Contradiction.
